# Masking in different scenes

Tags: rendering, objects, scene, compositing-nodes, freestyle

I am a bit confused how to manage my problem.
I have got a setup of a building site with several cameras and about 150 objects. Now I want to emphasize one of these objects by using freestyle.
Due to the many objects I created a new scene with only lighting, the emphasized object and another one that I turned to holdout. To exclude all objects except the emphasized one from freestyle by using the collection option is set. This works fine so far.

But I try to assemble one file using the compositing nodes from the emphasized rendering and the rest of the site witout freestyle in just one render.
The problem is, when I switch in th object properties the mask option holdout it is set over all scenes.

How can I fix this to decide in which scene the holdout should be used?

Thanks in advance
Lutz

[image: This is what I expect to get but I can only get the result while changing mask settings between rendering]

This is what I expect to get but I can only get the result while changing mask settings between rendering.
[image: And this is what I get when rendering both scenes with compositing.]

And this is what I get when rendering both scenes with compositing. The black area is supposed to be transparant in my resulting picture.

compositing setup
[image]

And here is the *.blend file:

[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your compositing setup. Also did you make sure to save the image in a format that supports alpha channel ?

Comment: @Gorgious The alpha channel is not the the problem because the black box is rendered as holdout in both scenes. So if I saved the alpha channel correctly we would see only alpha :-). I post the screenshot of the compositing setup in the post above (or can I attach pictures in comments? Didn't find this!)

Comment: From what I understood you need to also render the back wall in another pass, you can duplicate the object in another view layer or another scene and use a different material

Comment: @Gorgiuous: The backwall is not the point. The issue is that parts of the white pump which I outlined using freestyle are hidden behind the machine it's attached with. Therefor I used the holdout option. But I want this option to be sett differently between scenes.

Answer (score 0):

O.k. got it. The hint of Gorgiuos sent me to the desired direction. If I duplicate the object LINKED (Alt + D) then I can switch different options to the scenes and don't have to care about mesh updating between scenes and rising file size.

Thanks so far.